# I need to open latest modified (latest time stamp) file from my shared drive (google) in colab (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to open a file from my shared drive (google) in colab (python). But I need to open only the latest modified file. I tried the below code which is working, after I mount my google drive to colab. But I need to open directly from the shared folder without mounting the drive.

```
path.Cakare = path.join(max(glob.iglob('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/gdrive/DMS - Finance Data Pack/Chennai/DMS Cakare/CustomerMaster/asterik/asterik'),key=os.path.getctime))
dfck=pd.read_excel(path.Cakare)
```

Comment: Please highlight your code for clarity

Comment: Hi, Please review now.